# Definitive Guide To Removing Stains From Baby Clothes

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning

I'd like someone to explain, scientifically, what makes some baby clothes' stains so hard to remove, and what the right way to treat the stains is, chemistry-wise. A lot of internet sites have solutions (pardon the pun) that are 'my experience' and anecdotal, which is better than nothing, but not always transferable (and sometimes may damage clothes).

So yeah... how do you get out the hard to remove orange stains (e.g. from iron, or carrot/sweet potato soup)? How about other things? Why? I'd love someone to make this the definitive guide to removing stains from baby clothes, if you can :D. (Feel free to expand beyond my stated question above so there's just a one-stop reference question here.)

Answer (score 1):

Wash the garment in warm water with an enzyme detergent and oxygen bleach combo, such as Bio Kleen Oxygen Bleach Plus. To get rid of baby food stains, dunk the clothing in cold water, then soak the stain for at least 15 minutes in equal parts water and rubbing alcohol, which is safe for most fabrics when diluted.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Note that the OP explictly asked for the *chemistry* behind things, so your answer does not exactly hit the question.